# Classical random walk equation - confusion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, soft-question, probability

I have always thought that a (classical) on a straight line is governed by the binomial distribution: 
$$ {{n}\choose{k}} p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k},$$ $n$ being the number of tries and $k$ the number of successes.

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4780.pdf) they report the formula to be:

[image]

without defining what $T_n$ and $Y_i$ are.

Could anyone help me shed some light on how the last equation is derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have always thought that a (classical) on a straight line is governed by the binomial distribution: 
>   $$ {{n}\choose{k}} p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k},$$ $n$ being the number of tries and $k$ the number of successes.

This is not correct. If you want to be at position $k$ after $n$ steps, that mean you have to have gone forward $k$ more times than you went backwards. If $f$ is the number of times you went forward and $b$ is the number of times you went backwards, then you need
\begin{align}
f+b&=n\\f-b&=k
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}f=&\frac{1}{2}(n+k)\\b=&\frac{1}{2}(n-k)\end{align}
Then the number of way to get $\frac{1}{2}(n+k)$ steps going forward is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}n\\\frac{1}{2}(n+k)\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, and the probability of getting exactly $\frac{1}{2}(n+k)$ forwards and $\frac{1}{2}(n-k)$ backwards is $p^{\frac{1}{2}(n+k)}(1-p)^{\frac{1}{2}(n-k)}$. Thus in total, the probability for being at position $k$ is

$$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}n\\\frac{1}{2}(n+k)\end{smallmatrix}\right)p^{\frac{1}{2}(n+k)}(1-p)^{\frac{1}{2}(n-k)}$$
which is exactly what they give.

Note that all of this is only defined if $(n+k)/2$ and $(n-k)/2$ are integers, i.e. if $n$ and $k$ are either both odd or both even. This makes sense! After an even number of steps, you can only have gone an even amount of distance (think about it!) and after an odd number of steps you can only have gone an odd amount of distance. There's no way to have $k=1$ after $2$ steps. For $n$ even and $k$ odd or vice-versa, the probability is just zero.

Comment: Thanks this is great, so what is $Y_i$, $Z_n$ and $T_n$?

Comment: @SuperCiocia $T_n$ is the number of times you've gone forward (instead of backwards) at time $n$. $Y_i$ is a random variable which is 0 if you go backwards at time $i$, and 1 if you go forward. And $Z_n$ is your position at time $n$.